# Python objects inheriting each other's properties?

Tags: python, oop

I have a program in which I intend to compare the contents of a dictionary from two different instances of a class (I intend to make this a routing protocol simulation where FIB tables are compared) and it seems when I update the dictionary in one object, the other has its dictionary updated with the same information.

```
class bar:
    myName = ""
    mydict1 = {'a': '', 'b': ''}
    mydict2 = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.myName = name

    def addItem(self, x, y):
        self.mydict2[x] = y

foo = bar('a')

foo.addItem('a', 'test')
print(foo.myName, foo.mydict2)

foo2 = bar('b')
print(foo2.myName, foo2.mydict2)
```

The output of this is:

```
a {'a': 'test'}
b {'a': 'test'}
```

I'm not sure if this is a quirk with OOP in Python or if I am missing something else, hanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the attributes you declared outside `__init__` are *class* attributes (shared by all instances and the class itself), not *instance* attributes. If you want unique values for each instance, they must be initialized inside `__init__`, by attaching them to `self` (the instance being initialized), e.g.:

```
class bar:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.myName = name
        self.mydict1 = {'a': '', 'b': ''}
        self.mydict2 = {}

    def addItem(self, x, y):
        self.mydict2[x] = y
```

Side-note: Read up on [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. Your naming conventions are distinctly out of the ordinary, making your code harder to read (in particular, aside from built-ins like `int`, basically everyone uses `CapWords` for class names, and `lowercase` or `lowercase_with_underscores` for almost everything else).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since `mydict2` is assigned in the class rather than in the `__init__` method, it is a property of the class, not of an object. To get the behaviour you expect, assign a `self.mydict2` property in the `__init__` method.

If you are used to a language like Java, this could be surprising. The behaviour in Java is that when you declare a field in the class, it belongs to an instance unless it is explicitly declared `static`, and if the field has an initializer then the initializer is executed when the object is created.

In Python, all code in the body of a class is executed at the time the class is created. (This technically includes the method definitions, but note that executing a method definition just results in the method being declared, not called.) Since the code is executed only once, only one dictionary gets created, and the class holds a reference to it, though this reference can be accessed through any instance of that class.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!